# How to update an html input field using the DOM?

Tags: javascript

How do I update an html input field using the DOM? Here's what I've tried using the getElementsByClassName method:

```
<input type="number" class="price_input price_input_now" placeholder="Price in USD">

<script>
function myFunction() {

    document.getElementsByClassName("price_input price_input_now").setAttribute = "Some text";

    console.log("btn clicked");
}
</script>
```

click

The function is getting called - the console.log("btn clicked") is working. I tried .innerHTML, .innerText, and .setAttribute so far.

thanks!!

Comment: Getelementsbyclassname gives you an array of matching elements. Second, you can access the HTML value attribute using 'value'.

Comment: I see the real issue here is the mismatch of types.  You can't set an input type="number" to some text.  Are you trying to change the placeholder?  If that is the case then use Nandita's solution, perhaps with the substitution of getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the placeholder attribute like as shown below:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("price_input price_input_now")[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "Some text");
```

Also `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements so you need to select an index from that array.

```html
<input type="number" class="price_input price_input_now" placeholder="Price in USD">
<button onclick="myFunction()">button</button>
<script>
  function myFunction() {

    document.getElementsByClassName("price_input price_input_now")[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "Some text");

    console.log("btn clicked");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

An attribute is a value associated with a tag, for example with the anchor tag which is really `<a>`  but has the attribute `href=`.  What you are looking for is the value.

In this case your code will be much simpler if the input has an id.

What I see in this case is that you have a number input.  You can't set a number input to be text.

```
<input type="number" id="price_input" class="price_input price_input_now" placeholder="Price in USD">
```

For example:

```
document.getElementById("price_input").value = 100;
```

Snippet:

```js
  function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById("price_input").value = 100;
    console.log("btn clicked");
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="price_input" class="price_input price_input_now" placeholder="Price in USD">
<button onclick="myFunction()">button</button>
```

If you want to change the placeholder text, which is just an overlay and not actually a value, then you can set the placeholder, which IS an attribute of the input tag.

```
document.getElementById("price_input").setAttribute("placeholder", "Some text");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to put your attention on the following things:

- You are using input `type="number"`, which means that input will only
  accept **Numbers**, not Strings (e.g. plain text), so in your example "Some text" will not allowed to be set into input `type="number"`.
- [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) method returns **collection** of elements, not a single element. Since it's collection, you will be access to particular element via index property.
- Input has a property `value` which you could override with your
  value.

In total, the following code should do the thing:

`document.getElementsByClassName("price_input price_input_now")[0].value = 5;`

(please make note, that I've accessed to the `[0]` element of collection, which `getElementsByClassName` returns).

If you would like to put *"Some text"* value into your imput, you will need to change your input type to `text`.